# how Implement sms_configuration in terraform as optional?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm adding sms_configuration to my cognito module but... I still want to use null values... because there are times when a project is not going to use this attribute, it necessarily asks me to give them a value, is it required?

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pools" {
  for_each = var.user_pools
  name    = each.value.name    
  .... other atributes....

  sms_configuration {
    external_id    = ""
    sns_caller_arn = ""
    sns_region     = ""
  }
}
```

After apply:

> module.aws_user_pool[0].aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pools["analityc"]: Creating...
> ╷
> │ Error: creating Cognito User Pool: InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
> │ - missing required field, CreateUserPoolInput.SmsConfiguration.SnsCallerArn.

The idea was to use it only when sending values, in the tfvars... but in any case it requests that a value must be put in external_id and in sns_caller_arn.

If I don't use the block, if it does the apply correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use [`dynamic`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) in combination with [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta-argument. For example:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pools" {
  for_each = var.user_pools
  name    = each.value.name    
  .... other atributes....

  dynamic "sms_configuration" {
    for_each = var.sms_configuration_enabled ? [1] : []
    content {
      external_id    = ""
      sns_caller_arn = ""
      sns_region     = ""
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

You would then have to define the `sms_configuration_enabled` variable (type `bool`) and decide how to define other parameters required by the `sms_configuration` block.